# Progress bar in table cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

hi my table table cell is showing wired response ..i have a i had a coustom table table view with a button and progress bar in each cell ..when i clicked the button a book will download and then progress bar will appear until the book downloads but when i ever i clicked the second cell's button progress bar is appearing in 2nd cell and 4th cell....i very much confused with this please help thanks in advance

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Categorycell";

    Categorycell *cell = (Categorycell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Categorycell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    [tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
cell.cell_btn.tag       = indexPath.row*10+1;

    [cell.cell_btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnDown:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    cell.cell_ReadBtn.tag       =indexPath.row*10+1;
    [cell.cell_ReadBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnRead:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    cell.cell_Progress.tag= indexPath.row*10+1;

    if(!bIspress)
    {
    cell.cell_Progress.hidden=YES;
    }
    NSString *comicbook_id = [arr_comic_id objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"book_%@.pdf",comicbook_id];
    NSLog(@"Book Name : %@",filePath);
    if(![appDelegate check_Book_available:filePath])
    {
        NSLog(@"Book Name Not : %@",filePath);
    cell.cell_ReadBtn.hidden=YES;
        cell.cell_btn.hidden= NO;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.cell_btn.hidden=YES;
        cell.cell_ReadBtn.hidden=NO;

    }
    cell.tag=indexPath.row*10+1;
    return cell;
}



-(void)btnDown:(UIButton*)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Called when press");


   // sender.hidden = YES;
    dlIndex = sender.tag/10;
    bIspress=true;
    NSLog(@"INDEX : %d : %d",dlIndex,[sender tag]);
// Categorycell *cell = (Categorycell *)[self.tbl_view dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Categorycell"];
//    cell.cell_Progress.hidden=NO;
//    [cell.cell_Progress setProgress:0.];
    NSString *str_id=[arr_comic_id objectAtIndex:dlIndex];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:str_id forKey:@"book_id"];
   //     dlIndex = [sender tag]/10;
    dlCell = (Categorycell *)[[sender superview]superview];
    NSLog(@"INDEX progress : %d : Cell Tag : %d",dlCell.cell_Progress.tag,dlCell.tag);

     NSIndexPath *path = [tbl_view indexPathForCell:dlCell];
    if(dlCell.cell_Progress.tag==dlCell.cell_btn.tag)
    {

         [self Apicall_background];

    }

//    cell_Progressview = (UIProgressView* )[dlCell.contentView viewWithTag:dlIndex*10+1];
//    cell_Progressview.hidden = NO;




}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
-(void)btnDown:(UIButton*)sender
{

     //your code

     if(dlCell.cell_Progress.tag==dlCell.cell_btn.tag)
     {

          [self Apicall_background];
          CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(dlCell.bounds),
                                       CGRectGetMidY(dlCell.bounds));


          dlCell.cell_Progress.center = center;

     }
}
```

Comment: i am not asking position i need when i click table cell's button progress bar should be visible

Answer (score 0):

Bad solution but this should solve your problem.

```
Categorycell *cell = (Categorycell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
```

Comment: i am not asking position i need when i click table cell's button progress bar should be visible please help me

Comment: Did you tried this? You said that your progress bar is appearing in the correct cell and additional in another cell. So this is a quick fix.

Comment: [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil]; if i put nil at identifier means how it get in to tableview at what place u r telling to update please tell